# How to create arrow shoot functionality in cocos2d/ cocos2d-x

Tags: cocos2d-x

In my game i have some archers shooting arrows. i have applied ccJumpBy action currently to the arrows spawned with CCrotate action. My problem is that it is not looking realistic i.e. fast when they go up and fast when they come down but slow in between. I even tried CCEASEACTIONS to that but they started behaving just the opposite of what i am doing. i know jump action cant be broken into two parts directly. I even tried with ccbezier action but even that was not helping... here is my current code.

```
float angle = kShootRotationAngle;
CCPoint pos = ccp(troops->getSprite()->getContentSize().width/2 + gameLayer->winSize.width * 0.48, - winSize.height * 0.15);
float jumpHeight = winSize.height * 0.28f;
if (weaponType == kArrowTypeEnemyNormal || weaponType == kArrowTypeEnemyRapid || weaponType == kArrowTypeEnemyFire) {
    angle = - kShootRotationAngle;
    pos = ccp(troops->getSprite()->getContentSize().width/2 - gameLayer->winSize.width * 0.57, - winSize.height * 0.15);
}


jumpAction = new CCJumpBy;
jumpAction->initWithDuration(kNormalArrowMovementTime, pos, jumpHeight, 1);// Allocated Memory

rotateAction = new CCRotateBy;
rotateAction->initWithDuration(kNormalArrowMovementTime, angle);// Allocated Memory

spawnActions = new CCSpawn;
spawnActions->initWithTwoActions(jumpAction, rotateAction);// Allocated memory

removeWeaponAction = CCCallFunc::create(this, callfunc_selector(Weapons::removeArrow));// AutoRelease Type

delayAction = new CCDelayTime;// Allocated memory
delayAction->initWithDuration((kFrameCountElvesShoot - 3) * kArrowShootTimeElves + delay);

showSprite = new CCFadeIn;// Allocated Memory
showSprite->initWithDuration(0.0f);

delayBeforeDeletion = new CCDelayTime; // Allocated Memory
delayBeforeDeletion->initWithDuration(kDelayBeforeArrowDestroy);

sequenceAction = new CCSequence; // Allocated Memory
sequenceAction->initWithTwoActions(delayAction, showSprite);

sequenceAction2 = new CCSequence; // Allocated Memory
sequenceAction2->initWithTwoActions(spawnActions, delayBeforeDeletion);

sequenceAction3 = new CCSequence;// Allocated memory
sequenceAction3->initWithTwoActions(sequenceAction, sequenceAction2);

sequenceAction4 = new CCSequence; // Allocated memory
sequenceAction4->initWithTwoActions(sequenceAction3, removeWeaponAction);

arrowSprite->runAction(sequenceAction4);
```

Comment: Well, if you want it to look realistically, why not use a physics engine? Cocos comes with Box2D and Chipmunk.

Comment: thanks........ somehow able to complete it using ease action only